# What is the usual definition of a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $R$ be a ring.

I found there are two distinct definitions:

> Wikipedia Definition
>
> $a\in R$ is a zero divisor iff there exists nonzero $b\in R$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$.

Another:

> Proof wiki
>
> **nonzero**  $a\in R$ is a zero divisor iff there exists nonzero $b\in R$ such that $ab=0$ or $ba=0$.

Which one is the usual definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference here is whether you consider the zero element to be a zero divisor, which varies greatly based on the author's preference. For example, Atiyah & Macdonald considers zero to be a zero-divisor but Dummit & Foote does not.

Comment: I love Dummit&Foote!